# Rails using Formtastic I need to edit/update my data using Ajax, how can I do that ?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'am building a application using Ruby on Rails, and I choose to use Formtastic and implemented Ajax(Rails) to create the form, but now I have to EDIT and UPDATE the forms, so I like to use Formtastic too. 
So I can't pass the method PUT to the edit/update for using the **semantic_form_for**. 
How could I do that ?

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@cliente, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: if `@cliente` records is not a new record, then it will do `PUT/PATCH` request, `@cliente` is new record then it will do `POST` by default. U don't need to mention the HTTP verb for this.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript